# Making Jack work with Alsa on Raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, alsa, jack

I have a working Raspberry Pi 3B. 
The OS is Raspbian Stretch.

Default on-board Broadcom audio disabled.

USB SoundBlasterG1 audio card plugged in and configured as **hw:0**

`nano /etc/asound.conf`

> pcm.!default {
>     type plug
>     slave {
>       pcm "hw:0"
>     }
>   }
>
> ctl.!default {
>    type hw
>    card 0
>   }

I am able to play wav sound file using aplay like this

`> aplay hello.wav`

> Playing WAVE 'hello.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono

I am able to record wav sound file using arecord like this

`> arecord foo.wav`

> Recording WAVE 'foo.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono

I am able to run Jack server like this

`> jackd -d alsa`

> loading driver ..
>   creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
>   configuring for 48000Hz, period = 1024 frames (21.3 ms), buffer = 2 periods
>   ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 16bit little-endian
>   ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
>   ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 16bit little-endian
>   ALSA: use 2 periods for playback

However Jack doesn't seem to capture any signal from the microphone:

if I run

`> jackd -v -d alsa`

I get the following additional output

> new buffer size 1024
>   resizing port buffer segment for type 0, one buffer = 4096 bytes
>   resizing port buffer segment for type 1, one buffer = 2048 bytes
>   registered port system:capture_1, offset = 4096
>   registered port system:capture_2, offset = 8192
>   registered port system:playback_1, offset = 0
>   registered port system:playback_2, offset = 0
>   ++ jack_sort_graph
>   ++ jack_rechain_graph():
>   -- jack_rechain_graph()
>   -- jack_sort_graph
>   1160 waiting for signals
>   load = 0.0452 max usecs: 21.000, spare = 23198.000
>   load = 0.0678 max usecs: 21.000, spare = 23198.000
>   load = 0.0791 max usecs: 21.000, spare = 23198.000
>   (..etc)

**What do I need to setup Jack to capture data from my USB audiocard microphone using ALSA driver on Raspberry PI.**

Answer (score 0):

With Jack, capture and playback ports are not connected automatically.

One can connect ports either via UI app **qjackctl** or via cli using **jack_connect**.

Qjackctl package is usually listed as dependency for jackd, jack_connect script is bundled with jackd.